# Flutter - Text Field display date after date picked

Tags: flutter

I am basically trying to create a signup screen for my app. I have already included all of the other `TextFormField` for the other data. However, I am now stuck on the date input section, I managed to create a `TextFormField` wrapped in a `GestureDetector` where it will open a date picker to select a date once the `TextFormField` is tapped. My problem is I want to set the value of the the date `TextFormField` with the date selected in the date picker, I don't know why with the code that I have it is very inconsistent, at times it does display the date and other times it doesn't update and keeps showing the `hintText`, and also since there is a date picker popping up when the field is tapped, how could I disable the keyboard from showing when focusing on the date field.

```
class DateState extends StatefulWidget {
  const DateState({
    Key key,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _DateState createState() => _DateState();
}

class _DateState extends State<DateState> {
  DateTime selectedDate = DateTime.now();

  Future<Null> _selectDate(BuildContext context) async {
    final DateTime picked = await showDatePicker(
        context: context,
        initialDate: selectedDate,
        firstDate: DateTime(1950),
        lastDate: DateTime.now());
    if (picked != null && picked != selectedDate)
      setState(() {
        selectedDate = picked;
      });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var dateValue = TextEditingController();
    return DateFieldContainer(
      child: GestureDetector(
        child: TextFormField(
          controller: dateValue,
          onTap: () {
            _selectDate(context);
            dateValue.text = "${selectedDate.toLocal()}".split(' ')[0];
          },
          decoration: InputDecoration(
            hintText: "Select Date",
            focusedBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
              borderSide: BorderSide(color: PrimaryColor),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just replace your `_selectDate()` with below code.

```
void _selectDate(){
    showDatePicker(
      context: context,
      initialDate: selectedDate,
      firstDate: DateTime(1950),
      lastDate: DateTime.now(),
    ).then((pickedDate) {
      if (pickedDate == null) {
        return;
      }

      setState(() {
        selectedDate = pickedDate;
        dateValue.text = "${selectedDate.toLocal()}".split(' ')[0];
      });
    });
  }
```

Replace your `onTap()` implementation with below code

```
onTap: () {
            _selectDate();
          }
```

Keep **var dateValue = TextEditingController();** outside build() method.

Comment: Thank you @Alpesh Rathod for answering. I have already tried it and it is still not changing the value. Do I also have to remove the Future<Null>?

Comment: @Vinny it should work there is no requirement of returning Future<Null>.

Comment: I got it, it's working. Thank you @Alpesh Rathod! I removed something that I shouldn't have when trying out your code.